# jquery datatables: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" after destroying and reinitializing. Table as data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My initial initialization of DataTables() loads the table with serverSide datatables.

```
Data.columns = [];
  $('th').each(function(item,i){
    Data.columns.push({'data': $(this).text().trim()})
  });

  $('#searchtable').DataTable({
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': '/api/v1/reports/?format=datatables',
    'columns': Data.columns
  });
```

When a user performs a custom (non-datatables) search, I make an ajax request to a non-datatables api function. The api function sends a response back, I do `$('#searchtable').DataTables({ destroy : true })`, the table is cleared and reloaded with new data, and I reinitialize the table.

Here is the function that loads the new (search-generated table):

```
Template = {
    fill_search_table : function(data){
        Data.table = $('#searchtable');
        Data.table.html('');

        var $thead = $('<thead/>', {});
        var $tbody = $('<tbody/>', {});

        var header_values = Object.keys(data[0])

        var $thead_tr = $('<tr/>');

        $thead.append($thead_tr);
        $(header_values).each(function(i, item){
            var $th = $('<th/>', {
                text: item
            })
            $thead_tr.append($th);
        });

        Data.table.append($thead);

        cells = new Array(header_values.length).fill(0);
        $(data).each(function(i, item){
            var $tr = $('<tr/>', {});
            $tbody.append($tr);
            
            for(cell in item){
                cell_header_index = header_values.indexOf(cell);
                var $td = $('<td/>', {
                    text: item[cell]
                })
                cells[cell_header_index] = $td; 
            }
            $(cells).each(function(j, cell){
                $tbody.append(cell)
            })
        })

        Data.table.append($tbody);
        Data.table.DataTable({destroy: true})
        Data.table.DataTable({
            bPaginate: false,
            bFilter: false,
            bInfo: false,
        });


    },
}
```

When reinitializing the table, I get:  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

What is going wrong?

Comment: Exactly where do you get that error?  I suspect it's `Data.table.append($tbody);` - in which case you need to destroy the *existing* table first before adding new rows to it.

Comment: Putting destroy before .append($tbody) results in "Cannot reinitialize table" error. That said, the table, I think, gets reinitialized, but only partly, it seems.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yea, there seems to be an initialization, but there is no data in the actual datatable, and the data that was in the DOM table is put after it (empty first tbody row, then the DOM table)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was appending <td> to <tbody> instead of to <tr>